# What is the purpose of clearing global credentials?

Tags: discussion, support, logout

I have opened [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)  and [meta.stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) in different tabs(private browser).  *When I logout from meta.stackoverflow I'm still logged in stackoverflow(tried refreshing multiple times).*  I'm not sure about this behavior, because it is clearing global credentials  then other sites should also be logged out right?

Comment: Pretty sure each site keeps its own cookies.

Comment: @TheGrinch I thought it will logout all the SE sites throughout the browser.

Comment: I find it far easier to just use incognito mode on any computer I don't own than trying to figure out how the SE logout system actually works. The few times I tried logging out the result was pretty much always not what I expected.